# How to XQuery an {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array element

Tags: arrays, xml, xquery, osb

:

I'm trying to query a Array element with a XQuery Transformation in OSB OEPE, and put the queried elements in another Array element.

This is a example of what I need to query

```
<complexType name="QueryToneEvt">
   <sequence>
      ...
      <element name="allowedChannel" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
      ...
   </sequence>
</complexType>
```

The ArrayOf_xsd_string element is this:

```
<complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
   <complexContent>
      <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
         <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
      </restriction>
   </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Then, for a query over the allowedChannel element, I did this operation

```
for $i in $queryToneEvt/allowedChannel/?
return
     ¿?
```

From this, i have a few questions?

1. The Xpath route is correct for that element?
2. How I determine the type of the root Array member and the target Array member where I must put the queried Array member? (in the ¿? symbols) NOTE: The target Array have the same structure as the root, because it has the same type ArrayOf_xsd_string.

Comment: I tried to extract the elements with a for, like a "list" or unbounded element, but this doesn't do anything. I saw that the elements inside the Array are referenced with a href attribute, but i don't know how to query through that attribute. I was googling this several time, but the info I found didn't help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Likely not, because usually you need to provide a namespace. Or just use "any namespace":

   ```
   for $i in $queryToneEvt/*:allowedChannel
   ```
2. I do not understand your question. If the source and the target of the same type, just copy the root element as-is, including the attributes.

Please provide the examples of source and target structures, it is easier to see once.